# How to run different web pages in C++ and FCGI on Nginx?

Tags: c++, nginx, web, fastcgi

I follow the following tutorial to create a web page with C++ and FCGI running on Nginx.

```
http://chriswu.me/blog/writing-hello-world-in-fcgi-with-c-plus-plus/
```

After I run the following command lines, everything works perfect!

```
g++ main_v1.cpp -lfcgi++ -lfcgi -o hello_world

spawn-fcgi -p 8000 -n hello_world
```

But this is for one page. If I want to run 2 or 3 pages such as `about` or `contact`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 ways of doing it:

1. (best way) you re-write your default fastcgi application and add handler for every page/request you need
2. (ugly way) you write 2 additional fastcgi applicaiton and launch them on different ports, then change your `nginx.conf` to serve specific requests like `/about` or `/contact` with different fastcgi applications with [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) directive

Comment: so for option 1, I need to use if-statements and based on the query string to return the right page?

Comment: @OConnor, yes, it might be `if-else` or `switch` statement, anything you feel comfortable for now